# ETRS89 proyections in R and ArcGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, r, arcgis-10.6

I have a shape file in ETRS89 CRS created with ArcGIS 10.6, prj file says:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

If I the create a shape file in R, with the `sf` library, using the same projection, epsg = 4258:

```
Gasolineras <- st_transform(GasolinerasWGS84, crs = 4258)
sf::st_write(Gasolineras, 'Gasolineras.shp')
```

and then I read it bakc into ArcGIS, it complains, because they are **not** in the same CRS.

[image]

But they are!

Looking at the prj file created by R, it looks a bit different than the one created by ArcGIS, but they differ only in the labels, not in the parameters:

```
GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

It says datum "D_unknown", so it appears that ArcGIS understand that the proyections are different.

Is they any way to avoid this, and force R to write particular labels in the prj file of a shape file?

Comment: Make sure that GCS of the data frame, you are importing shapefile from R, should be the same as the shapefile itself.

Comment: I don´t import a shapefile into R. I just create it from a csv file of coordinates, using the `sf` library, and then write it as a `shp`file.